# Keep Sidebar From Pushing Down Content, Put in Middle on Small Screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble with a right-sidebar of varying heights pushing down other content that's on the left, like this:

[image: a right-sidebar of varying heights pushing down other content that's on the left].

My main content is in a col-md-9 div, the sidebar is in a col-md-3 div, and comments should be right below the main content in another col-md-9 div. Right now if the sidebar is extra long, the comments get pushed down so they start on the left where the sidebar ends on the right. However, when I make the screen small, the flow is correct: main content, content from sidebar, and comments, like this:

[image: the flow is correct: main content, content from sidebar, and comments].

I've tried adding rows, getting rid of rows, changing up the order of the divs, and changing float directions. What can I do to get rid of the extra space and to still have the three divs go into the right order on smaller screens when the sidebar is long, like this:

[image: How I want the medium-width screen to look]

This is the code in general:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  MAIN CONTENT
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h1>Conversation:</h1>
  <h2>COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS COMMENTS 
</div>
```

Here is [a CodePen](http://codepen.io/MichelleGlauser/pen/BNoKLd) I've been playing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rearrange your divs to fix that problem. Also you should give importance to sidebar last.

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-9">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      Content
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
     Comment
    </div>

  </div><!--row-->

</div><!--col-md-9-->

<div class="col-md-3">
  Sidebar
</div><!--col-md-3-->

</div><!--main-row-->
```

Comment: Thanks. What could I have googled to find out more about this? I looked at "Bootstrap" with scaffolding, offset, push, rows, column pushing content down, etc.

Comment: This is all just logic.

Comment: So a row doesn't act like a horizontal row? That doesn't seem logical to me. I think what you mean is that it makes sense to someone who's used Bootstrap a lot.